# Error to implementation of strategy pattern in C++

Tags: c++, linux, c++11

I'm trying to implement the design pattern strategy in C++.
The goal for me is to do an operation on 2 numbers.

Here is my context class

```
  operation::operation(std::unique_ptr<calculatorTask> pTask = nullptr)
{
    pCalculatorTask = std::move(pTask);
}

operation::~operation();
{
}

void operation::setTask(std::unique_ptr<calculatorTask> pTask)
{
    this->pCalculatorTask = std::move(pTask);
}

void operation::executeTask(numberMsg& sValues)
{
    pCalculatorTask->calculate(values);
}
```

This is my implementation :

```
int main()
{
   std::vector<std::unique_ptr<calculatorTask>> myOperation;
   myOperation.push_back(std::move(std::unique_ptr<additionTask>(new additionTask())));
   myOperation.push_back(std::move(std::unique_ptr<substractionTask>(new substractionTask())));
   for (const auto &Ope : myOperation)
    {
        pOpe->setTask(Ope);
        [...]
    }
}
```

I have this error :

> error: use of deleted function ‘std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&) [with _Tp = calculatorTask; _Dp = std::default_delete]’
> pOpe->setTask(Ope);

I don't understand error and how to fix it.

Comment: `setTask` accepts `unique_ptr` while you want to pass `(const) unique_ptr&`. In such situation C++ tries to create a copy, but obviously `unique_ptr` is not copyable. There's something wrong with your design: `setTask` wants ownership but you create `std::vector` of `unique_ptr`. Looks like two owners to me. What exactly you are trying to accomplish? Perhaps you want to use `shared_ptr` instead?

Comment: @freakish. I reworked my design, i replace unique_ptr to shared_ptr. My error has been fixed. Thanks for your answer